# in C posix how to have timestamp?

Tags: c, date, timestamp

hi guys  how  is possible  have timestamp  in C  ?  in  bash is  easy  date +"%s"  , but  in C i not  find  nothing  about this only if  you have  timestamp and  want  convert in normal date but  viceversa ? or  exist a simply command like in bash?

````
  time_t     now;
  struct tm  ts;
  char       buf[80];

  // Get current time
  time(&now);

  // Format time, "ddd yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"
  ts = *localtime(&now);
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &ts);
  printf("%s\n", buf);```
````

Answer (score 1):

The functions you're looking for are [`strptime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) and [`strftime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)

`strptime` will parse a string date into a `tm` struct, and `strftime` will format the `tm` struct to a string.

It's fairly trivial to convert the `tm` struct to and from a POSIX timestamp.

Stolen from the referenced man page:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(void)
{
    struct tm tm;
    char buf[255];

    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
    strptime("2001-11-12 18:31:01", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d %b %Y %H:%M", &tm);
    puts(buf);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Converting to/from the `tm` struct is best done with the [`gmtime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gmtime.3.html)/[`timegm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html) pairs.

Comment: thanks  so much for  answer  ,   but  i use  this solution  much simple and fast  
    printf("Timestamp: %d\n",(int)time(NULL));